# Neural network regression with confidence interval implemented with Keras

Tags: regression, neural-networks, deep-learning, keras

When using neural network for classification problem, and using softmax as last layer for last layer.

Typically, we have a prediction and a confidence level. However, is there such confidence interval measure for neural network regression problem?

Answer (score 4):

You would have to output vectors of means and standard deviations rather than discrete values to achieve that.

One solution to get those vectors would be variational inference - generate those, sample w/reparametrization, then optimize so the results of the sampling match the original values like in normal regression (i.e. MSE/MAPE/MAE/whatever loss) and regularize the means and stddev to 0/1 respectively.

Essentially the same process as a vanilla Variational Autoencoder, except you're not bound by the Autoencoder architecture, and you want the means/stddevs as the outputs of the trained network rather than the sampled values.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on how you would get the network to output the means and standard deviations alongside the actual predicted target value?

Comment: You just use two neurons per each latent space dimension, one for the mean, one for stddev, and your final 'concrete' output is a sample drawn from the resulting distribution (possibly processed by further hidden layers). Just by having a sampling layer consistently treating the two outputs as mean/stdev and backprop, the outputs wind up effectively _being_ those things.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @jkm I was quite fascinated by the idea of implementing confidence intervals for regression in Keras. Personally, I hope it would boost my model network's performance as I have multiple supervised DL models on different datasets that are being fed into a single Reinforcement Learning Algorithm. Hence, the RL 'parent' would be able to know how confident the individual model is at a given time.

I went with a different approach to implementing a custom loss function (as I need the two neuron outputs without any Keras magic of printing hidden layer outputs...). If at the end of the model you have a `Dense(2)` layer, then you have an output of size `[batch_size, 2]`. The problem is that `tf.random.normal` needs two separate tensors for the mean and std. So you need to transpose the output.

**The Loss Function with MSE:**

```
class RegressionDistLoss(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RegressionDistLoss, self).__init__()
        self.mse = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        x = tf.transpose(y_pred)
        x = tf.random.normal([y_pred.shape[0]], x[0], x[1])
        # print(x) # tf.Tensor([-0.2107901  3.8580756  1.8032494], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
        return self.mse(y_true, x)
```

**Val. Experiment:**

```
y_true = tf.constant([0, 4, 2], dtype='float32')
y_pred = tf.constant([[0, 1], [3.5, .5], [2.2, .7]], dtype='float32')
x = RegressionDistLoss()(y_true, y_pred)
print(x) # <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0344286>
```